# Child Jobs don't cancell scope in Kotlin coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile

I'm trying to learn about cancel propagation in Jobs. I thought if a Job get's cancelled, its father too.

```
val cancellableScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default + Job())
val cancellableScope2 = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default + Job())

runBlocking {

    cancellableScope2.launch {

        cancellableScope.launch {
            throw Error("1")
        }.join()

        cancellableScope.launch {
            println("2")
        }.join()

    }.join()

    cancellableScope2.launch {

        delay(200)
        println("llegó 3")

    }.join()

}
```

I get the next output:

```
Exception in thread "DefaultDispatcher-worker-2" java.lang.Error: 1
    at MainKt$main$1$1$1.invokeSuspend(Main.kt:21)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)
    Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@430de60, Dispatchers.Default]

3
```

I expected to only get the error, but "3" get's printed too. Isn't "cancellableScope2" cancelled when first launched fails too?

I tried changing to the same context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you're in `cancellableScope2.launch` scope you use explicit parent scope when launching here:

```
cancellableScope2.launch {

    cancellableScope.launch {
        throw Error("1")
    }.join()

    cancellableScope.launch {
        println("2")
    }.join()

}.join()
```

That means those jobs are descendant of `cancellableScope` only and have no relation to `cancellableScope2`, so they are free to collapse without affecting state of `scope2`.

The thing you might be confused about is that `launch`-ed jobs don't return any result. You do `join` on them but it's just a delay until they're complete. Whether they succeed, fail or get cancelled doesn't matter.

However if instead of `launch` + `join` you use [`async`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/async.html) and [`await`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/async.html) you'll get the behavior you expect. That creates a [`Deferred`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/async.html) which does return a result so in this case `await` would rethrow `Error(1)` which will collapse `scope2`.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. I tried giving cancellableScope the outer context manually and it worked well. It seems that I didn't understand corroutine launching context inheritance that well :)